# Xamarin iOS Free Provisioning - No Matching Profiles Found

Tags: ios, xamarin, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have been following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=windows) guide on setting up free device provisioning for iOS apps in Xamarin, however Visual Studio never seems to locate a provisioning profile.

I get through all the XCode steps without issue, even deploy the blank XCode project to my iPhone without issue.

When I get to step 8 of the "Deploy your Xamarin.iOS app" section however (the Visual Studio tab), the signing identity doesn't exist, nor does the provisioning profile (see the below image).

[image]

[image]

If I attempt to run my application the output window does show it found the correct profile and certificate:

> 1>    Code Signing Key: "Apple Development: *[Redacted personal email]* (A248A6WF6F)" (B30BFAAA304EE99F25656BDA0095A97BA3104EDF)
> 1>    Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.companyname.mytestapp1" (c38b8ce4-f892-440f-991e-17287768105b)
> 1>    Bundle Id: com.companyname.mytestapp1
> 1>    App Id: BG3U7QRUKM.com.companyname.mytestapp1

But then the deploy fails with the following output:

> ApplicationVerificationFailed: Failed to verify code signature of /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.aEefsk/extracted/mytestapp1.iOS.app : 0xe8008015 (A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.)

And my error window shows:

> Error error MT1006: Could not install the application '/Users/matt/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/mytestapp1.iOS/e472585bbe370a429acd1bb065d6b3f2ebe6b76f1907d868be01a91463b888f9/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone12.1-15.2/mytestapp1.iOS.app' on the device 'Matt???s iPhone': AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle returned: 0xe8008015.

I've hit a wall on getting this working and hope you lot can give me something to work with. I can export the certificate as a .p12 file from XCode, but I haven't found any way to import that into Visual Studio. It's also worth noting that Visual Studio is on a Windows PC, then I have a MacBook as my build host, and the iOS device is connected to the MacBook via USB.

Comment: Do one thing - open the project in Xcode ( open any Xib, or storyboard with Xcode) then you let Xcode fix it for you with "Automatic provisioning" then quit Xcode, Quit VS, relaunch VS that generated credential should be available.

Comment: I've tried this and it did not work. I don't suppose you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I've had an issue with my VS on WIndows not seeing it either, I gave up and just use my Mac for iOS deployment/coding now

Comment: Have you tried to login the Apple Accounts in `Options-Xamarin-Apple Accounts` first?

Comment: Logging in to the Apple Accounts requires a paid Apple Developer account, which kind of defeats the purpose of free provisioning.

Comment: Did you use Xcode to create a signing identity and provisioning profile  first : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=windows#use-xcode-to-create-a-signing-identity-and-provisioning-profile?

Comment: Yes I did @ColeX-MSFT, as I mentioned I got through all the XCode steps without issue and even managed to deploy the blank XCode project to my iPhone without issue.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio 2022? I'm sure It was working before when I used VS2019 , I will report this to my team and you can also raise the issue on github : https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues .

Comment: I've tried both VS2019 and VS2022 @ColeX-MSFT, neither have worked.

Comment: It could be a potential issue with visual studio , as I mentioned before , feel free to raise this issue on github for better support.